# show no-parent div on click on another div, pure css possible?

Tags: html, css

I want to split my site in two vertical sections. If you click on a left button (width:50%), the content for this button should appear below with width:100% and if you click on the right button the same but of course with content 2.

Is it even possible with pure css? Because I don't know java :/ and I think it's a quite simple problem, isn't it?

```css
#content_button_left,
content_button_right {
  display: none
}

#button_left:active~#content_button_left {
  display: inherit
}

#button_right:active~#content_button_right {
  display: inherit
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display:flex">
    <div id="button_left" style="flex:1">Menu left</div>
    <div id="button_right" style="flex:1">Menu right</div>
  </div>

  <div id="content_button_left" style="width:100%">
    blabla 1
  </div>

  <div id="content_button_right" style="width:100%">
    blabla 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First `Because I don't know java` , i think you are refering to javaScript which has nothing to do with `java`. Second, with your current html structure you cannot do that with CSS. In order to do smth like this only with CSS you would need a relationship between the button and it's content ( parent->child, sibling-sibling ). WHich you don't have. You are using the general sibling selector `~` but your items are not siblings. Plus, if it's such a simple problem, why don't you solve it yourself? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use radio buttons next to the content and labels for your button targeting the radios.  This way you can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to only show the content next to a checked radio:

```css
/* hide radio and content */
.radio,
.content {
  display: none;
}

/* show content if it directly follows a checked radio */
.radio:checked + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display:flex">
    <label id="button_left" style="flex:1" for="left-input">Menu left</label>
    <label id="button_right" style="flex:1" for="right-input">Menu right</label>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="show-content-radio" id="left-input" class="radio">
  <div id="content_button_left" style="width:100%" class="content">
    blabla 1
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="show-content-radio" id="right-input" class="radio">
  <div id="content_button_right" style="width:100%" class="content">
    blabla 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!! That was what I was searching for :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use :target CSS selector to fake the click event but for that you have to convert your div to anchor tag, below is CSS

```
#content_button_left, #content_button_right{
display:none
}

#content_button_left:target {
display:block;
}

#content_button_right:target{
display:block;
}
```

Updated HTML

```
<div style="display:flex">
     <a id="button_left" href="#content_button_left" style="flex:1">Menu left</a>
     <a id="button_right" href="#content_button_right" style="flex:1">Menu right</a>
  </div>
  <div id="content_button_left" style="width:100%">
      blabla 1
  </div>
  <div id="content_button_right" style="width:100%">
      blabla 2
  </div>
```